# Linqer dont Convert T-Sql query

Tags: c#, linq, linqer

I using linqer want this sql to liqn query but i have problem

```
 select * from Project where Id in (select Top 3 ForeignId from ActivityLog
 group by ForeignId order by count(*) desc)
```

Problem :SQL cannot be converted to LINQ: Field [Id in (select Top 3 ForeignId from ActivityLog group by ForeignId order by count(*) desc)] not found in the current Data Context.

Comment: Can you supply some more info, eg. your sourceode that is not working?

Comment: is it self-explained? ID  not found in the current Data Context

Comment: I assume from the reference to DataContext that this is Linq to SQL. What you have posted does not appear to be a Linq query, it is raw SQL. Try posting the actual C# code that is invoking the query.

Comment: How sound is your DataContext? Can you write linq queries at all that fetch Projects and ActivityLogs in one shot? It is better anyhow to start expressing your programming tasks in terms of the classes in your DataContext and thus become proficient in linq.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue with linqer.  I found the solution was removing the ; after the SQL query and trying again.

It could be an issue with your context.
See [Linqer – a nice tool for SQL to LINQ transition](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2011/01/24/linqer-a-nice-tool-for-sql-to-linq-transition.aspx) for instructions on setting up the context.
Also, make sure the *.dbml and *.designer.cs files are up to date and define the Project table to contain an Id column and the ActivityLog table to contain a ForeignId column.

This could be a bug with the version of linqer you are using.  I am using 4.0.3 and was able to run the same query (adjusted to use my tables) without issue.